# How to use Clang with C++ Modules in Windows 10

Tags: cmake, windows-10, clang++, c++-modules

I wanted to start testing and learn modules and move out of the days of header files and see if the experience differs. I installed everything required (Visual Studio module option in the installer), but Clang doesn't seem to be able to resolve the imports. When I switch over to MSVC on the other hand, it works fine. I'm currently working with VS 2019 Insider preview.
So, how so I get clang (10, the latest release) to work?

EDIT: The error in question is `module not found` with Clang. MSVC works fine. What flags do I need to pass to Clang so that it can find the modules installed my VS-Installer? For example, I pass CLI argument to MSVC to enable modules.

EDIT: 
C++ File (main.cpp):

```
import std.core;
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello CMake from C++20!\n" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

CMake file

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.16)  

project ("cpp20" LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE)

add_compile_options(
    "$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/experimental:module>"
)

add_executable (cpp20 "main.cpp" )

add_compile_options(
    "$<$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>:/experimental:module>"
#   something here to let Clang use modules. I tried -fmodules, 
#  -fmopodules-ts, -fbuiltin-module-map, -fimplicit-module-maps CLI, but none work.
)
```

So, how do I get Clang to find the modules install by VS, or modules that it might have installed.

Here is a [zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vsvJtNMhPuWkBBgp8RxpO28TVR_MBTo7/view?usp=sharing) of the sample "Hello World" project.

Thank you.

Comment: It is **requirement** of the Stack Overflow to have the code **in the question post** itself, not *linked*. See [ask].

Comment: I don't want to post a wall of text here. It's a starter project. Easy enough to reproduce on a computer.

Comment: You boil it down to a hello world example with two files and modules and a five-line CMakeLists.txt file. If it is not enough, add some lines to make the problem reproducable.

Comment: It _is_ a hello world project, as mentioned in the comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake does not support C++ modules. Once it is officially supported, you can expect it to work. Until than, the compiler or msbuild might do some magic, but you cannot rely on it.

Comment: I can add CLI flags right? I just keep getting the error `module std.core not found`. I've tried basically all module related flags to pass to the compiler.

Comment: Not sure what you do without a minimal example.

Answer (score -1):

```
add_compile_options("-fmodules -fbuiltin-module-map")
add_link_options("-fmodules -fbuiltin-module-map")
```

and you can use standard library modules, but not make your own, this requires more steps and they are not supported by cmake at this point.